# How do i change the order of the coordinate labels in xarray?

Tags: multidimensional-array, coordinates, scatter-plot, python-xarray

When I create a xarray dataArray, I am able to set the labels of the coordinates in the order I want to but when I then use .combine_first to add some data from a different array to it, it always reorders the labels alphabetical. Then I want to plot the data in a facet line plot with multiple data in one graph, and here I get the problem, that the order of the labels of the coordinates define which line gets ploted above the other. Is there a way to reorder the labels after I combined the data, or how I get to choose which line gets ploted above the others?

Here an example with the coordinate Labels of 'type' which are not in the correct order

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import xarray as xr
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
            
            
    data1 = np.random.randn(4, 4,3)
    type = ["b", "c", "a", "d"]
    loc= np.linspace(1,3,3)
            
    times = pd.date_range("2000-01-01", periods=4)
    foo = xr.DataArray(data1, coords=[times, type, loc], dims=["time", "type","loc"])
    foo
        
Out[1]: <xarray.DataArray (time: 4, type: 4, loc: 3)>
array([[
                   ...
                         ]])
Coordinates:
    * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-02 2000-01-03 2000-01-04
    * type     (type) <U1 'b' 'c' 'a' 'd'
    * loc      (loc) float64 1.0 2.0 3.0
```

Here I make a second array and combine it with the first one:

```
 data2=np.random.randn(4,1,3)
    type2 =["b"]
    loc2= np.linspace(1,3,3)
    times2 = pd.date_range("2000-01-01", periods=4)
    foo2 = xr.DataArray(data2, coords=[times2, type2, loc2,], dims=["time", "type","loc"])
    foo2
    comb=foo.combine_first(foo2)
    comb
Out[2]: 
<xarray.DataArray (time: 4, type: 4, loc: 3)>
array([[[-2.45206949e+00, -1.39563427e+00,  4.01038823e-01],
        ...
        [-1.60937495e+00,  1.23864314e+00, -3.89573178e-01]]])
Coordinates:
  * type     (type) <U1 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-02 2000-01-03 2000-01-04
  * loc      (loc) float64 1.0 2.0 3.0
```

After .combine_first the labels 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'  are reorderd alphabetical.
Here is the way I want to plot it and where the order of the lines I want to change

```
t=comb.plot.line(x="time", col="loc", linewidth= 5, col_wrap=3)
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljcoW.png)

Comment: does [`da.sortby('type')`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.sortby.html) do the trick?

Comment: unfortunately not, this lets you only sort them alpabetical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DataArray.sel` to order the array along a coordinate to your liking (here I am using the `type` list you defined in your question):

```py
comb.sel(type=type).plot(x="time", col="loc", linewidth= 5, col_wrap=3)
```